# Delete or remove data from grid table, not delete the entire row only data in the grid table

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to move datas from grid-table4 to grid-table3. The problem is grid-table4 can only hold one raw of data and when the function calls data from grid-table4 moves to 3, but I can not add any item into the grid-table4.

```
function reset() {

    var RowList;
    RowList = $('#grid-table4').getRowData();
    var Row;
    for (Row in RowList) {
        $('#grid-table3').addRowData(Row, RowList[Row]);
    }
    $('#grid-table4').clearGridData();

}
```

Comment: What values you want to use as rowid? **I think that id duplicates is your main problem.** Do you use different `idPrefix` values in both grids? It's the simplest way to prevent id duplicates. Which `datatype` have the grids? You wrote "grid-table4 can only hold one raw of data". Why only one row? One more way to fill the grid with any unique id values is the usage of `$.jgrid.randId()`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't set any unique id values for the rows in the grids (rowid). It seems that only the data itself have an interest for you. In the case I would recommend you to generate new unique id vale for grid-table3 with respect of `$.jgrid.randId()`.

```js
function reset() {
    var $gridSrc = $("#grid-table4"), $gridDest = $("#grid-table3"), i, data;
    data = $gridSrc.jqGrid("getRowData");
    if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $gridDest.jqGrid("addRowData", $.jgrid.randId(), data[i]);
        }
        $gridSrc.jqGrid("clearGridData");
    }
}
```